# JOIN on keys that don't have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to do an INNER JOIN on two tables that have similar values, but not quite the same. One table has a fully qualified host name for its primary key, and the other the hosts short name, as well as the subdomain. It it safe to assume that the short name and the subdomain together are unique.

So I've tried:

```
SELECT table1.nisinfo.* FROM table1.nisinfo INNER JOIN table2.hosts ON (table1.nisinfo.shortname + '.' + table1.nisinfo.subdomainname + '.domain.com') = table2.hosts.fqhn WHERE table2.hosts.package = 'somepkg';
```

This doesn't return the results I expect, it returns the first result hundreds of times. I'd like to return distinct rows. It takes a long time to run as well.

What am I doing wrong? I was thinking of running a subquery to get the hostnames, but I don't know what the right path from here is.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please share both table structures ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case, I used a subquery to get the initial results, and then used a join.

```
SELECT table1.nisinfo.* FROM table1.nisinfo JOIN (SELECT distinct(fqhn) FROM table2.hosts WHERE package = 'bash') AS FQ ON ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(FQ.fqhn, '.', 1)) = table1.nisinfo.shortname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by in your query so you can achieve the desired results you want
please see this two links

[Group by with 2 distinct columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594536/group-by-with-2-distinct-columns-in-sql-server)

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your results into a temp table and then view the table to make sure that the columns are as expected.

```html
SELECT table1.nisinfo.*, table1.nisinfo.shortname + '.' + table1.nisinfo.subdomainname + '.domain.com' AS ColID
INTO #temp
FROM table1.nisinfo;

Select * 
from #temp INNER JOIN table2.hosts ON @#temp.ColID = table2.hosts.fqhn 
WHERE table2.hosts.package = 'somepkg'
;
```

Put a Group By clause at the end of the second statement